# Set audio output priority on OSX

Tags: macos, audio, macos-sierra

I would like to know how to set priority of Audio Output devices on macOS Sierra.  I have an external Dell docking station that I sometimes plug into the USB-C port, and this device has an audio controller and headphone jack that's separate from internal output.  I want it to take priority over internal speakers - especially when I have my headphones plugged in.

Comment: macOs doesn't have prioritised audio in that way, other than headphones overriding speakers. You could set up a hot-keyed Service to switch, though. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217148/using-apple-script-to-manage-sound-output-selection for the underlying script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Audio MIDI Setup utility:

1. Plug your headphones into the headphone jack on the docking station.
2. Launch the "Audio MIDI Setup" utility.
3. In the Audio MIDI Setup window, you'll see a list of audio devices on the left side. Click on the "+" button at the lower left corner and select "Create Aggregate Device".
4. A new Aggregate Device will appear in the list. Click on it to select it.
5. On the right side of the window, you'll see a list of audio devices that can be included in the Aggregate Device. Check the box next to your Dell docking station's audio controller to include it.
6. Drag the devices in the list to set their priority order. Place the Dell docking station's audio controller at the top of the list, so it takes priority over other audio devices, including the internal speakers.
7. Close the Audio MIDI Setup utility.

Now, whenever you connect your Dell docking station, your Mac should automatically switch audio output to the headphone jack on the docking station.

Comment: Step 6 doesn't work for me. I can't figure out how to drag the devices. However, the order in which I click the "Use" checkboxes lets me set the priority.

Comment: Overall, this _almost_ works, but when I use the Aggregate Device for output, I can no longer control the volume with my MacBook laptop keyboard's volume controls.